# The biggest smallest and middle number

Tags: python

I have 3 inputs of numbers and cannot figure out why the middle number is not working.
It is working with numbers like 1 2 3
But if you go with 150 100 50 you will get the following result:
biggest is 150 and other 2 50
Here is the code:

```
a = int(input('Your first number: '))
b = int(input('Your second number: '))
c = int(input('Your third number: '))

def largest(a, b, c):
    if (a > b) and (a > c):
        largest_num = a
    elif (b > a) and (b > c):
        largest_num = b
    else:
        largest_num = c
    print('The largest number is: ', largest_num)

def smallest(a, b, c):
    if (a < b) and (a < c):
        smallest_num = a
    elif (b < a) and (b < c):
        smallest_num = b
    else:
        smallest_num = c
    print('The smallest number is: ', smallest_num)

def average(a, b, c):
    if (a > b) and (a < c):
        average_num =a
    elif (b > a) and ( b < c):
        average_num = b
    elif (c > a) and (c < b):
        average_num = c
    else:
        average_num = c
    print('The average number is: ', average_num)

largest(a, b, c)
average(a, b, c)
smallest(a, b, c)
```

Comment: WHy not just sort the list of a, b, c?

Comment: Where is the problem the output is correct

Comment: Can you define what do you mean by the average number?

Comment: @BemwaMalak Average = middle of the 3, like it says in the text.

Comment: Did you by any chance experience the problem ***before*** you added `int()` to convert inputs.

Comment: The correct word in math is "median".

Comment: @PM77-1 If it were that problem it would say that 50 is the largest.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
a = int(input('Your first number: '))
b = int(input('Your second number: '))
c = int(input('Your third number: '))

def largest(a, b, c):
    largest = max([a,b,c])
    print('The largest number is: ', largest)

def smallest(a, b, c):
    smallest = min([a,b,c])
    print('The smallest number is: ', smallest)

def average(a, b, c):
    if c<a<b or b<a<c:
        average_num = a
    elif a<c<b or b<c<a:
        average_num = c
    elif c<b<a or a<b<c:
        average_num = b
    else: #else all numbers are equal
        average = a
    print('The average number is: ', average_num)

largest(a, b, c)
average(a, b, c)
smallest(a, b, c)
```

or you could just do:

```
a = int(input('Your first number: '))
b = int(input('Your second number: '))
c = int(input('Your third number: '))
lst = [a,b,c]
lst.sort()
print("smallest = %s" % lst[0])
print("average = %s" % lst[1])
print("maximum = %s" % lst[-1])
```

Comment: it will use `a`

Answer (score 0):

`elif (b > a) and ( b < c):`

This line only works in the case that `b` is bigger than `a` and smaller than `c`.

But it doesn't work if `b` is bigger than `c` and smaller than `a`.

You can try:

`elif ((b > a) and ( b < c) or (b < a) and ( b > c)):`